# ShowDialog with MdiParent Issue VB:NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, mdiparent

Actually i'm trying to show and dialog into a parent form, An reference example is:

```
Parent      Parent_child    dialog
Main_form   new_invoice     new_invoicedialog
```

I Tryed this code But it says:

```
Private Sub invoice_new_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp

            With new_invoicedialog
                .MdiParent = Main_Form
                .Owner = Me 'invoice_new
                .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
                .ShowDialog()
            End With

End Sub
```

Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling showDialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you remove `.MdiParent = Main_Form` it will work. You're trying to show a modal dialog, which isn't the same thing as an MDI form.

Comment: I researched and I've noticed that i can't display a dialog inside a form MDi, but thank you for your time

Comment: I must be misunderstanding the problem. I have a project right here with an MDI Form which has a child form, and there's a button on the child form which launches a modal dialog. Is that not what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a main form (MDI Parent), now into the mdi parent display and Child form and into this Child display a Dialog. :

Answer (score 0):

I know this is real late but it might prove helpful to someone else that may come across this as I did when researching this issue. You could do smt like:

```
newTransaction.MdiParent = Me
Me.Enabled = False
newTransaction.Show()
Me.Enabled = True
```

It allows you to still run the forma as a child but turns off the parent form until the child is closed, then it makes it available again.

Comment: Your code is not working. YOu cannot access showdialog if the dialog is came from child of the parent